# Explicit Login with Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

According to the WL official document, all the authentication happen as the following scenario.

1. a client request for a protected resource
2. server invokes the client side ChallengeHandler::handleChallenge()
3. At the client side, in the handleChallenge(), it would invoke 
   ChallengeHandler::submitAdapterAuthentication

My question is 
I have tried another alternative. Call the following directly.

1. ChallengeHandler::submitAdapterAuthentication

For now, everything works fine for me. And I wonder if there's any side effects of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the documentation indeed states what you wrote...
Yes, this type of "pro-active authentication" should be fine to work with none the less.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Could you please give me a reference to the "pro-active authentication"? I need some evidence to persuade my boss.

Comment: There is none available.